# Map SharePoint 2016 On-Prem Document Library as a Network Drive with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, network-drive

I am trying to map a SharePoint 2016 on-prem document library as a shared drive.

I can map it manually but I am trying to do it with PowerShell

my document library url is http://mysharepointinstance/sitename/documentlibrary

**Note: site is not SSL configured and code will execute on a Windows 10 box**

```
$LibraryPath = "\\mysharepointinstance@SSL\DavwwwRoot\sitename\documentlibrary"
New-PSDrive -name "R" -Root $LibraryPath -PSProvider filesystem
```

but I am getting error

```
The specified drive root "\\mysharepointinstance@SSL\DavwwwRoot\sitename\documentlibrary" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your script in my environment which was configured SSL, it worked fine.

Also, I tested your script in my environment which was not configured SSL, I got the same error message as yours.

So, your issue is caused by you didn’t configure SSL in your environment.
Please refer to the following article to configure SSL:
[Configure SSL for SharePoint 2013/2016](https://sharepointdiv.wordpress.com/2018/05/04/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013-2016/)

If you don’t want to configure SSL, you can try the following script :

```
#Variable
$LibraryPath = "http:// mysharepointinstance/sitename/documentlibrary"

#Map Path as Network Drive
$Network = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$Network.MapNetworkDrive('R:', $LibraryPath)
```

Comment: worked, thank you.